# How to create a netcat relay on OS X?

Tags: macos, smtp, postfix-mta, netcat

I'm trying to troubleshoot my postfix so I decided to route its traffic to my isp smtp relay trough a netcat relay:

```
nc -l <someport> 0<backpipe | nc <isp-smtp> 26 | tee backpipe
```

And I configured my postfix to connect to localhost:. But to get the netcat relay working it needs a FIFO pipe made with `mknod backpipe p`  and apparently this is not supported on OS X.

Is there an alternative way to either set up a TCP relay I can monitor, or something else I can use to watch the chit-chat between postfix and my isp smtp?

Comment: why do you think making named pipes isn't supported on OS X?

Comment: mknod on os x does no support 'p'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under Leopard, mkfifo is in /usr/bin.  Not sure about prior.

```
/usr/bin/mkfifo backpipe
```

personally I'd recommend using tcpdump and/or wireshark, it gives you a nicer view of the traffic too.